# Override all methods Xcode 6 shortcut, swift language

Tags: swift, xcode6

I need to get all the methods for the delegate that I'm extending and also the methods I need to overide after inheritance. Is there a shortcut for doing this in Xcode 6 with Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here is a good way to handle something like that. Use custom code snippets:

First highlight the code you want to be able to autocomplete later. Then click and drag it down into the code snippet collection:

[image]

After this, you can go into the code snippet and edit its properties:

[image]

You are then good to go! Just start typing out your `completion shortcut` text and hit `tab`:

[image]

All of the code you wanted will pop up. You can create as many custom code snippets as you need to accomplish what you are after!